# Getting document size when printing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to change the size of a google chart when printing a page.

To get a callback when printing is executed i am using:

```
if ("matchMedia" in window) {
  window.matchMedia("print").addListener(((media) => {
    if (media.matches) {
      this.beforePrintHandler();
    } else {
      $(document).one('mouseover', this.afterPrintHandler);
    }
  }).bind(this));
}

$(window).on("beforeprint", this.beforePrintHandler);
$(window).on("afterprint", this.afterPrintHandler);
```

The problem is that the document size is equal to the size of the webpage instead of the size of the page to be printed when using the onbeforeprint event.

When using matchMedia, the document size is equal to the print page size.

Unfortunately IE and Firefox won't trigger on 'print' media change.

Any help is appreciated!